# Where to ask about when to switch to another technology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about publishing of webapplications in asp.NET and PHP, but I'm not sure where to ask it (Stack Overflow or Programmers Stack Exchange)? I have problems when deploying websites in .net, I find it not easy, time consuming, a lot of configuration is needed and very few hosting providers (mostly high prices).

I feel like I'm forced to learn PHP just because it's very simple to publish and there are a lot of hosting providers (even free ones). Should one leave a technology or switch to another technology just because he/she experiences the mentioned difficulty?

I explained my problem, now I need to know where I should ask for help.

Comment: That all reads rather opinion-y. Perhaps a chat would be more suitable?

Comment: "Questions about what language, technology, or project one should take up next are off topic on Programmers, as they can only attract subjective opinions for answers. There are too many individual factors behind the question to create answers that will have lasting value." (that's a quote from official [meta-tag:close reasons] at Programmers)

Comment: You should google "PHP Singularity" to get SO founder Jeff Atwood's take on whether you should learn PHP.

Comment: Thanks @Wooble It sounds interesting.

Comment: Funny.  I have, on many occasions, thrown together micro websites and published them to Azure (where they don't even consume enough resources to result in a charge) within minutes (under an hour). Son, if you're having problems, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Won't you think everyone has the budget to publish on Azure. Money is also a factor to keep in mind.

Comment: @BJJer: I think everyone has the budget? Thanks for peeking into my mind for me. Protip: you're still doing it wrong. Before you count something out of your budget, you should actually see how much it costs.

Comment: Dude, what do you mean by wrong? Wrong because I don't publish my websites to Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions asking for advice on which technology to use or if you need to switch is opinion based and therefore not suitable for any current stack exchange sites.

Area 51 has recently re-started their previously closed [Software Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) Proposal, where such a question would seem at home to me. So if you follow them early then soon your question will have a place on their stack exchange when it is released. 
As far as I can tell, your question is asking to Recommend whether you should learn a new Software, so it wouyld be the correct place.

If you are looking to improve yourself as a person, there is the [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

If you want to improve your employability, the [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange would be the correct place to ask.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone for technology recommendations. To me it seems a question on how to keep productive and improve myself. But I think I have to reform the question without mentioning any technology or language by name.

Comment: @BJJer Added more options for you to look into for different facets of your question.

Comment: Accepted your answer as it: "is opinion based and therefore not suitable for any current stack exchange sites."